# unlock the of nokia N97 during the execution of application

Tags: java-me

I am working with nokia N97.And my application is in j2me.Problem i am facing is when i am executing the application the lock mobile.and screen get blank.And i have to again and again unlock that lock.

I want to always keep the lock of mobile as unlock so that it can never get unlock during the execution of my application.Is there any setting does i have to do?or changes in my code I have to do??

Please help me out of this???
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this with J2ME, you have to use Symbian C++/Python/QT to access this kind of functionality.